# PL/SQL package body

Tags: function, plsql, package, procedures

I have this package, is there any way i can access the body of the functions and procedures in it? I am new to PL/SQL.

```
 create or replace PACKAGE        pkg_tracking IS  


FUNCTION fnc_proyecto_asignado(i_pry_id IN proyectos.pry_id%TYPE, 
                               i_usr_codigo IN usuarios.usr_codigo%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER;

FUNCTION fnc_verifica_evaluacion_tarea (i_trs_id IN tareas.trs_id%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2;

FUNCTION fnc_verifica_observacion_tarea (i_trs_id IN tareas.trs_id%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2;

FUNCTION fnc_verifica_ordenativo_tarea (i_trs_id IN tareas.trs_id%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR2;

FUNCTION fnc_fecha_facturacion_tarea (i_trs_id IN tareas.trs_id%TYPE) RETURN DATE;

FUNCTION fnc_fecha_cierre_tarea (i_trs_id IN tareas.trs_id%TYPE) RETURN DATE;

PROCEDURE prc_instancia_tarea (i_trs_id        IN NUMBER,
                               o_orden_compra OUT VARCHAR2,
                               o_recepcionada OUT VARCHAR2,
                               o_facturada    OUT VARCHAR2,
                               o_cobrada      OUT VARCHAR2);                                  


END pkg_tracking;
```

Comment: You can access the [package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS009) body in the same way that you're accessing the package specification you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the ALL_SOURCE view, it's pretty self explanatory

Or better yet, get an IDE - [TORA](http://torasql.com/%20TORA) is OK and free.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search in the below 2 tables: `All_users` and  `Dba_users` :

```
Select * from all_users where name='package name'  and type='package body';
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue